# Relative referencing of columns when calculating another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating difference of two columns in dataframe like this

`cases['7dayIncrement'] = (cases['10/15/20'] - cases['10/8/20'])`

However, I need to change this to **relative** values, being `last column - 7th column from last`. The dataset gets new column added every day.

I was trying something like `cases['7dayIncrement'] = (cases.iloc[:,-8,-7] - cases.iloc[:,-1:])` but that doesn't seem to work, throwing `IndexingError: Too many indexers`.

Any suggestions how is this done, please?

Comment: `df.diff(periods=7, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, You are looking for something like this:

```
cases['7dayIncrement'] = (cases.iloc[:,-1] - cases.iloc[:,-7])
```

last col would be : cases.iloc[:,-1]
and 7th col from last would be: cases.iloc[:,-7]

Comment: Thank you, exactly. I just couldn't figure out the syntax and find the docs.